# Jquery access specific element from multiple elements with same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-multiselect

Hello I'm trying to implement multiple Kendo multiselect and both of them have the same class(.k-multiselect .k-input) that is generated by kendo at runtime, I'm trying to access the second multiselect using the
`var input = $('.k-multiselect .k-input').val();`
`var input = $('.k-multiselect:nth-child(2) .k-input').val();`
and `var input = $('.k-multiselect .k-input:nth-child(2)').val();`

But when I remove the other multiselect and try to access it using
`var input = $('.k-multiselect .k-input').val();` it is working as expected.

Any idea on how to access the specific elements, My second multiselect has a attribute `aria-describedby="mtuProeducts_taglist"`

Comment: Do you know the ID's of each - if so, just use that: $("#myID").data("kendoMultiSelect").value()

Comment: If you can't do that - you can try comparing the results of $('.k-multiselect .k-input') and $('.k-multiselect .k-input:nth-child(2)') in the developer tools, and inspect what the second one is returning compared to the first which works

Comment: To add on top of what G_P asked, if you don't have an `id` on the second multiselect, give it an `id` and then use it in your jQuery selector.